# Azure Application Insights selecting first occurrence of event with name in session

Tags: azure-application-insights

I want to select a first occurring  `customEvents` for given name for in session

Following query gives the first event by session

customEvents
   | summerize min(timestamp) by session_Id

But it only returns `timestamp` and `session_Id`

How to get other properties also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using [arg_min()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-min-aggfunction):

```
customEvents | where timestamp > ago(24h) | summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by session_Id
```